# How to cleaning document.body after each test globally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using [Jasmine gem](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem) in my Rails project for testing JavaScript. My tests add some HTML to document.body. I want it to be clean before each test. Is there a way to clean it globally for all tests in all test files? I do not want to put the cleaning in beforeEach in each suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can here are two ways;)

1. Put the beforeEach on your runner. Here's the [docs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Before-and-After) with concrete example.
2. You can use [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery)'s fixtures or see how it's done there if you don't need jQuery. With it, whenever you create a fixture it's automatically cleaned up after the test.